# Automatic align div onclick between page margins

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a list of products with an hidden div inside.
When I click on the product, the hidden div should open and show details.

As you can see from the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/K8E4p/) the last hidden div, when clicked, is opened outside margins.

**jQuery to open the hidden div**

```
function activateDropdown(entry_id) {
    $(".box-dropdown").hide("slow");
    $("#box-dropdown-" + entry_id).show("slow");
}
```

Is there a way to "align" it respecting margins? (the site is responsive, so decreasing the viewport the green divs could also be 3 or 2...)

**UPDATES:**

- I want that the hidden square when opened should be 4x4. It has to be places over other 3 divs. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/K8E4p/1).
- The hidden div has to be opened from left-to-right, but obviously for the last square it has to be right-to-left.

Comment: so you want the window to open a to the `left` or from `left-to-right`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/K8E4p/4/)

2 changes you need to do :

**first change**, set how the divs opening from right to left have to behave DOM-wise, if its a fixed dive, i'll suggest using `nth-child(4n)` kind of property for that

```
#box-dropdown-4{
    right:0;
}
```

**then**, place a condition in JS for the `div`s who is going to open from right to left, again if it is 4th div always, use something like `entry_id%4 == 0` to identify!

```
if (entry_id != 4) {
        $("#box-dropdown-" + entry_id).show("slow");
    } else {
        $("#box-dropdown-" + entry_id).show('slide', {
            direction: 'right' /* decide slide direction, yeah, its that simple :) */
        }, 20000);
    }
```

**most imp note :** m not a JS person, so animation is not smooth :)

Answer (score 1):

just use this css

```
   #box .box-dropdown {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background: #ffffff;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 5;

        }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqkBA/)

changed :

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I missed a spec in my question, I want that the hidden square when opened should be 4x4. It has to be places over other 3. Check the updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IronFeast/K8E4p/1/

Comment: @Mark: did you checked it /

Comment: Is there a way to automate it? Example, as I wrote in the 1st question (the site is responsive, so decreasing the viewport the green divs could also be 3 or 2...), if in that position I found the 3rd, I have to fix it case by case.